# Float left item in nav menu go bottom after zoom 90% etc

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a navigation menu, but last item after zooming out, for example at 90% zoom goes down. "Five" is located under "Four" item. Navigation should be static in size and span one line, not two. All items should occupy the entire size of the div#page (960px, 192px*5) in one bar.

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}
#page {
  background-color: #777272;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 170px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0px 20px 0;
}
a:visited {
  color: white;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="page">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">One "1" One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Two "2" Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Three "3" Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Four "4" Four</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Five "5" Five</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <ul class="clear">
                    <li>Tomato</li>
                    <li>Cucumber</li>
                    <li>Carrot</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want a responsive navbar?

Comment: static, i used pixels.

Comment: @Nishant or responsive navbar, if you know how to create

Comment: Check I did it for you..

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this style:

```
nav ul li {
  float: left;
} // not needed
```

and add this style:

```
  nav ul {
       list-style-type: none;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       display: flex; // this has been added
    }
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1c2gsn34/

EDIT: In 33% UI is breaking, due to `width:170px`.  Please remove the width from `a` instead of width use

```
  nav ul li {
            flex: 1;
          }
```

Comment: i don't know "flex" attribute, for compatibility with older browsers is better to use only `inline`,`block`,`inline-block`. and see what happens if you zoom out of the page at 30%, page exits to the right. this is not a good solution in my opinion

Comment: @light123 flex is supported in all browsers, until and unless you are giving support to Internet Explorer 9.  https://caniuse.com/?search=flex

And the issue which is happening at 33% is due to your CSS. I've updated my answer.

Comment: i want any technique, but without `flex` or any template which will look like the one shown. But I mean it won't come apart and the menu will remain in "one bar" layout

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go this is what you want.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Source : [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav)**

Comment: Is this what you want? if yes let me know

Comment: no, i think about https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_topnav_equal_width.asp but with borders. Edit: maybe that's not the best example because in my case  here is the static size 960px.

Comment: Can you share screenshot which of navbar you want